# How To Validate Crossed Time Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, validation

I have the time data in my database like this

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
|    id       | time_start | time_end   |
+---------------------------------------+
|    1        |  07:00     |  10:00     |
|    2        |  12:00     |  14:00     |
|             |            |            |
|             |            |            |
|             |            |            |
|             |            |            |
|             |            |            |
|             |            |            |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

but i'm insert time crossed,

```
time_start : 08:00
time_end : 09:00

or

time_start : 08:00
time_end : 11:00
```

How to validate if the *time_start* and `time_end` not between date in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you the way to do that in raw SQL, feel free to translate it into eloquent rigmarole:

```sql
SET @tstart='10:00';
SET @tend='11:00';

INSERT INTO t_time_range (time_start, time_end)
SELECT @tstart, @tend 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1 
         FROM   t_time_range
         WHERE  time_start >= @tstart AND time_start < @tend
         OR     time_end > @tstart    AND time_end <= @tend
         OR     @tstart >= time_start AND @tstart < time_end
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your model is `time`, the time you want to enter are `$time_start` and `$end_time`.

```
$time = DB::table('time')
->where(['time_start', $time_start], 
        ['time_end', $end_time])
->first(); // see if there already is an entry
```

If $time has no result, enter the time in database.